# Cannot 'insert into' with variables in php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, insert-into

Great, now I can 'insert' into the database, but in phpmyadmin the fields are white, without content... This is the php code:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$institution = $_POST["institution"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$country = $_POST["country"];
$hcp = $_POST["hcp"];
$texto = $_POST["texto"];
$state = $_POST["state"];
$license = $_POST["license"];

$consulta = ("INSERT INTO `1264`(`name`,`institution`,`email`,`country`,`hcp`,`texto`,`state`,`license`) VALUES ('$name','$institution','$email','$country','$hcp','$texto','$state','$license');");

mysql_query($consulta,$connection) or die("You cannot register. Try it later, please.");
```

Does anybody know why?

Comment: you don't need to give the id

Comment: Remove extra `,` after `license`

Comment: When this will work, it sill be a huge security gap. You should read about prepared statements at least, and sanitize user input as much as possible if not already done.

Comment: Removed...but it still doesn't work...

Comment: add `echo $consulta`;  between the two lines and please show us the output of that line - that will show the text that gets sent to the db server.

Comment: What happened to the extra commas in the question? That was the problem, now the answers make no sense.

Comment: This was the old code: $consulta = ("INSERT INTO `1264`(`name`,`institution`,`email`,`country`,`hcp`,`texto`,`state`,`license`,) VALUES ('$name','$institution','$email','$country','$hcp','$texto','$state','$license',);");

Comment: Please be aware that the mysql extension (supplying the `mysql_` functions) has been deprecated since 2012, in favor of the mysqli and PDO extensions. It's use is highly discouraged. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your query

you have extra ',' both after  `'license'` and  `'$license'`

```
 $consulta = ("INSERT INTO `1264`(`id`,`name`,`institution`,`email`,`country`,`hcp`,`texto`,`state`,`license`) VALUES (NULL, '$name','$institution','$email','$country','$hcp','$texto','$state','$license');");

 mysql_query($consulta,$connection) or die("You cannot register. Try it later, please.");
```

Also try using mysqli_* functions. mysql_* functions going to deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$consulta = ("INSERT INTO `1264`(`id`,`name`,`institution`,`email`,`country`,`hcp`,`texto`,`state`,`license`) VALUES (NULL, '$institution','$email','$country','$hcp','$texto','$state','$license');");
```

ie, remove the extra comma at the last

Comment: You still have the extra comma after `license`.

Answer (score 0):

Dont make the query so clumpsy. Here is a simple edit,

```
$consulta = "INSERT INTO `1264` SET 
    `name` = '$name',
    `institution` = '$institution',
    `email` = '$email',
    `country` = '$country',
    `hcp` = '$hcp',
    `texto` = '$texto',
    `state` = '$state',
    `license` = '$license'";
```

You don't have to write the id and leave its value field null, it will be auto generated by default.

Answer (score 0):

if id is an primary key then it should not be null
and if it is an  auto increment  field have no need to put it on field list and value
  $consulta = ("INSERT INTO `1264`(`name`,`institution`,`email`,`country`,`hcp`,`texto`,`state`,`license`,) VALUES ( '$name','$institution','$email','$country','$hcp','$texto','$state','$license',);");

do echo $consulta ;

to check if the query is coming properly or try put the variables out of cote check the name one

```
VALUES ( '".$name."','$institution','$email','$country','$hcp','$texto','$state','$license',)
```

Answer (score -1):

Removed the last comma and Id -> NULL so try this:

```
`$consulta = ("INSERT INTO` `1264`(`name`,`institution`,`email`,`country`,`hcp`,`texto`,`state`,`license`) VALUES `('$name','$institution','$email','$country','$hcp','$texto','$state','$license');");
```

Comment: Although your answer is quite probably correct, please add a short description about what you changed to make it work, for posteriority.

Comment: You haven't fixed the extra comma after `license`.

Answer (score -1):

This should work -  enter each variable between quotes, especially when its a string

```
$consulta = ("INSERT INTO `1264`(`id`,`name`,`institution`,`email`,`country`,`hcp`,`texto`,`state`,`license`) VALUES (NULL, "'. $name ."','".$institution."','".$email."','".$country."','".$hcp.'","'.$texto.'","'.$state.'",'".$license."');");
```

Comment: You still have the extra comma. Why do you think changing from string substitution to concatenation will fix it?

Comment: You still haven't explained why you think it's necessary to use concatenation instead of interpolation. That's a personal style choice, it doesn't affect the validity of the code.